# TextFormField in flutter doesn't accept input and only flashes keyboard for 1 second

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

my TextFormfields only flash the keyboard for 1 second and don't accept input even when I try to paste it. I used textfields before and they worked great without causing this kind of problems but I need validators so I needed to switch to TextFormFields. Here is the code of the scaffold's body below :

```
body: Column(children: [
          SizedBox(height: height * 0.1),
          Center(
              child: Container(
            height: height * 0.1,
            width: width * 0.6,
            child: Image.asset("assets/f.png", fit: BoxFit.contain),
          )),
          SizedBox(height: height * 0.05),
          Center(
            child: Container(
                height: height * 0.4,
                width: width * 0.8,
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: name,
                      obscureText: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Name',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: height * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(
                      validator: validateEmail,
                      controller: emailAddress,
                      obscureText: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Email adress',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: height * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(
                      validator: validatePassword,
                      controller: password,
                      obscureText: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: height * 0.01),
                    Center(
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              _submit();
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: height * 0.05,
                              width: width * 0.4,
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text("Register",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.00)),
                            ))),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/s');
                        },
                        child: Text("Already have an account?",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)))
                  ]),
                )),
          )
        ])
```

Comment: can you try removing your validations ?

Comment: @ManishDayma Hi Manish, thanks for your answer. I need validators,  I can post them if you want to see them.

Comment: @ManishDayma I deleted them and the problem still exists

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?